# Get PID of the process which issued a Device Request in I/O Kit

Tags: macos, kernel, iokit

I'm currently experimenting with Apple's I/O Kit to develop a kernel module.

More in detail, I'd like to write a mock device driver (of type `IOUSBDevice`) which logs the name of the process that issued a device request, attempting to read from that device.

I stumbled upon some example code, and I found the signature of the `DeviceRequest` function, invoked presumably by the process which want to access the device:

```
IOReturn DeviceRequest(IOUSBDevRequestDesc *request,
                                           IOUSBCompletion *completion)
{ ... }
```

It seems that the `request` parameter carries some useful data, such as:

```
rdDirection: Direction of data part of request: kUSBIn or kUSBOut
rqType: Request type: kUSBStandard, kUSBClass or kUSBVendor
rqRecipient: Target of the request: kUSBDevice, kUSBInterface,
        kUSBEndpoint or kUSBOther
bRequest: Request code
wValue: 16 bit parameter for request, low byte first
wIndex: 16 bit parameter for request, low byte first
wLength: Length of data part of request, 16 bits, low byte first
pData: Pointer to memory descriptor for data for request
wLenDone: Set by standard completion routine to number of data bytes
     actually transferred
```

However, there's no direct way to figure out which process sent the request. The only element we have is the `pData` pointer, which points to the memory location of the process where the data will be stored.

Is there a way to obtain the caller process PID by using such pointer, or even in another way?

Answer (score 0):

`proc_selfpid()` should give you the right answer, unless the request is coming from a kernel driver, in which case the question isn’t especially well defined.

You may be better off tracking the task with which the `IOUserClient` that is generating the requests is associated. You may need to override the `newUserClient` method for this.